# Using AWS Glue Python jobs to run ETL on redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift, aws-glue, amazon-redshift-spectrum, aws-glue-workflow

We have a setup to sync rds postgres changes into s3 using DMS. Now, I want to run ETL on this s3 data(in parquet) using Glue as scheduler.

My plan is to build SQL queries to do the transformation, execute them on redshift spectrum and unload data back into s3 in parquet format. I don't want to Glue Spark as my data loads do not require that kind of capacity.

However, I am facing some problems connecting to redshift from glue, primarily library version issues and the right whl files to be used for pg8000/psycopg2. Wondering if anyone has experience with such implementation and how were you able to manage the db connections from Glue Python shell.

Comment: I can't answer your question as I have been repulsed by glue every time I try to use it.  It's a 70% solution that takes 100X the effort to get 71% out of it but this is just my opinion.  My thought for you is to look into Step Functions with Lambda actions.  It does what you want and is quite flexible.  It is also way cheaper than glue - both in terms of AWS cost and aggravation. Yes, it takes some coding to get started but I've found it to be much cheaper in the end - your mileage may vary.

Comment: If you have parquet files in S3, why not load them directly into Redshift, process it there and unload it. You can trigger this via step functions. And trigger the step function in EventBridge on a schedule. Or use Redshift scheduler directly (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/query-editor-schedule-query.html)

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing something similar in a Python Shell Job but with Postgres instead of Redshift.

This is the whl file I use

`psycopg_binary-2.9.2-cp36-cp36m-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl`

An updated version can be found [here](https://pypi.org/project/psycopg-binary/#files).